# parsing multiple json array using java

Tags: java, json

How to access the coldata from the given json array? also fromdate and todate and arrayName

> ```
> {
> ```
>
> "fromdate":1361912208000,
>      "todate":1361998608000,
>      "datavalues":[
>         {
>            "arrayName":"1st Array",
>            "datavalue":{
>               "rowvalues":[
>                  {
>                     "coldata":[
>                        "1",
>                        "5342",
>                        "75"
>                     ]
>                  },
>                  {
>                     "coldata":[
>                        "23",
>                        "4465",
>                        "75"
>                     ]
>                  }
>               ],
>               "colnames":[
>                  {
>                     "id":"id1",
>                     "type":"String",
>                     "label":"id"
>                  },
>                  {
>                     "id":"id2",
>                     "type":"Number",
>                     "label":"number"
>                  },
>                  {
>                     "id":"id3",
>                     "type":"Number",
>                     "label":"number"
>                  }
>               ]
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "arrayName":"2nd Array",
>            "dataTable":{
>                "rowvalues":[
>                  {
>                     "coldata":[
>                        "1",
>                        "5342",
>                        "75"
>                     ]
>                  },
>                  {
>                     "coldata":[
>                        "23",
>                        "4465",
>                        "75"
>                     ]
>                  }
>               ],
>               "colnames":[
>                  {
>                     "id":"id1",
>                     "type":"String",
>                     "label":"id"
>                  },
>                  {
>                     "id":"id2",
>                     "type":"Number",
>                     "label":"number"
>                  },
>                  {
>                     "id":"id3",
>                     "type":"Number",
>                     "label":"number"
>                  }
>               ]
>            }
>         }
>      ]
>   }

Comment: Have tried to loop through the array using JSONArray!              JSONArray obj1 = JSONUtil.getJSONArray(obj, "datavalues");
for(int i = 0; i <= jObj1.size(); i++) { 
JSONArray obj2 = JSONUtil.getJSONArray(obj, "datavalue");
for(int j = 0; j <= jObj2.size(); j++) { 

}
}

Comment: Put this in your question, what does not work?

Comment: :-) was not sure how many loops do I need to add to access coldata? So, posted the above question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing JSON, you need to have a Good [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) and a [JSON Library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java).
this helps you see the tree structure for your Array.

Here's what I see, [image]

So I've written some code to parse the first object in the datavalues array.

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONReader {

static String JSON_STRING = "{\"fromdate\":1361912208000, \"todate\":1361998608000, \"datavalues\":[ { \"arrayName\":\"1st Array\", \"datavalue\":{ \"rowvalues\":[ { \"coldata\":[ \"1\", \"5342\", \"75\" ] }, { \"coldata\":[ \"23\", \"4465\", \"75\" ] } ], \"colnames\":[ { \"id\":\"id1\", \"type\":\"String\", \"label\":\"id\" }, { \"id\":\"id2\", \"type\":\"Number\", \"label\":\"number\" }, { \"id\":\"id3\", \"type\":\"Number\", \"label\":\"number\" } ] } }, { \"arrayName\":\"2nd Array\", \"dataTable\":{ \"rowvalues\":[ { \"coldata\":[ \"1\", \"5342\", \"75\" ] }, { \"coldata\":[ \"23\", \"4465\", \"75\" ] } ], \"colnames\":[ { \"id\":\"id1\", \"type\":\"String\", \"label\":\"id\" }, { \"id\":\"id2\", \"type\":\"Number\", \"label\":\"number\" }, { \"id\":\"id3\", \"type\":\"Number\", \"label\":\"number\" } ] } } ] }";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create root JSON Object
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
    System.out.println(object.get("fromdate"));
    System.out.println(object.get("todate"));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    // Get Data Values
    JSONArray dataValues = object.getJSONArray("datavalues");

    System.out.println("------------- Data Values ---------------");

    JSONObject datavalue = dataValues.getJSONObject(0);
    System.out.println("Arrray Name : " + datavalue.getString("arrayName"));

    JSONObject dval = datavalue.getJSONObject("datavalue");

    System.out.println("------------- Row Values ---------------");
    JSONArray rowvalues = dval.getJSONArray("rowvalues");

    for (int y = 0; y < rowvalues.length(); y++) {
        JSONObject columns = rowvalues.getJSONObject(y);

        System.out.println("------------- Col data --------------");
        JSONArray coldata = columns.getJSONArray("coldata");

        for (int z = 0; z < coldata.length(); z++) {
            System.out.println(coldata.get(z));
        }
    }

    JSONArray colnames = dval.getJSONArray("colnames");

    for (int y = 0; y < colnames.length(); y++) {
        JSONObject columns = colnames.getJSONObject(y);

        System.out.println("------------- Col Names --------------");

        System.out.println(columns.get("id"));
        System.out.println(columns.get("type"));
        System.out.println(columns.get("label"));
    }

}
```

}

and the output

```
1361912208000
1361998608000
------------- Data Values ---------------
Arrray Name : 1st Array
------------- Row Values ---------------
------------- Col data --------------
1
5342
75
------------- Col data --------------
23
4465
75
------------- Col Names --------------
id1
String
id
------------- Col Names --------------
id2
Number
number
------------- Col Names --------------
id3
Number
number
```

I'm sure you can figure out the rest from there